# sendMail Intermittent Errors

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm sending messages using the Microsoft Graph REST API. My application is a service/daemon application where I am sending email on a users behalf. I am using the sendMail API (POST /users/{user id}/sendMail ) and this works a very large percentage of the time. The problem is that every so often the following error is returned:

{ "error": { "code": "UnknownError", "message": "", "innerError": { "request-id": "a901d503-8acf-47e7-8f7e-a20311aa0e3b", "date": "2017-01-10T15:06:48" } }}

Any idea what is causing this error and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs show that you're getting a 429 status code (which means throttling).

Is your app sending many requests for the same resource/user? If so, the [error docs](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/errors) say this:

> Client application has been throttled and should not attempt to repeat the request until an amount of time has elapsed.

Comment: Yes I am sending many requests for a user. How much time needs to occur before trying again? Is there anyway to disable the throttling for a specific user? Any guidelines on how many request will cause the throttling error?

Comment: Regarding how much time--in this case, Exchange returned a Retry-After=300. Microsoft Graph doesn’t currently pass that response header back to the client but there is an active Pull Request for this, so Microsoft Graph should start returning Retry-After for 429s soon.

Comment: I have slowed my email sending down to approximately 1 per second and yet I am still seeing this error. Will slowing it down more make a difference or is something else causing the errors to appear? I really need this to work consistently. I am sending these emails on behalf of a large office 365 customer.